# Retrieve out parameter of @SqlCall as List<String> in jdbi

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jdbi

`@SqlQuery` parses select answer into List if you want to. Example:

```
@SqlQuery("Select a.id from indexes a")
List<String> selectIds();
```

How can i parse out parameter of `@SqlCall` as List? I can't understand what type from `java.sql.Types` i should use. For example here:

```
@SqlCall("begin " +
         "SELECT a.id " +
         "BULK COLLECT " +
         "INTO :output " +
         "from indexes a; "
         "end;") 
@OutParameter(name = "output", sqlType = #Don't know what to put here#)
OutParameters selectIds();
```

---

**UPD.**
Tried this:

```
@SqlCall("begin " +
        "SELECT DISTINCT scu.LOGIN " +
        "BULK COLLECT " +
        "INTO :output " +
        "from sc_users scu; " +
        "end;")
@OutParameter(name = "output", sqlType = Types.ARRAY)
OutParameters selectIds();
```

Got:

```
org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: Exception while binding 'output' [statement:"begin SELECT DISTINCT scu.LOGIN BULK COLLECT INTO :output from sc_users scu; end;", rewritten:"begin SELECT DISTINCT scu.LOGIN BULK COLLECT INTO ? from sc_users scu; end;", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{output:org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.Call$OutParamArgument@45198fd9}, finder:[]}]
```

---

**UPD2.** Also tried this:

```
@SqlCall("declare " +
        "ar addressVarray; " +
        "begin " +
        "ar := addressVarray('asd'); " +
        ":output := ar; " +
        "end;")
@OutParameter(name = "output", sqlType = Types.ARRAY)
OutParameters getArray();
```

where `addressVarray` is `CREATE Or Replace TYPE addressVarray AS VARRAY(2) OF VARCHAR2(50);`

Got again:

```
org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: Exception while binding 'output' [statement:"declare ar addressVarray; begin ar := addressVarray('asd'); :output := ar; end;", rewritten:"declare ar addressVarray; begin ar := addressVarray('asd'); ? := ar; end;", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{output:org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.Call$OutParamArgument@46c22d8e}, finder:[]}]
```

Comment: [Please add a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ScaryWombat Added.

Comment: Maybe `java.sql.Types.ARRAY`

Answer (score 0):

See this example taken from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_c0052030.html

```
Connection con;
CallableStatement cstmt;
ResultSet rs;
java.sql.Array inPhoneData;
…
cstmt = con.prepareCall("CALL GET_EMP_DATA(?,?)");
                                            // Create a CallableStatement object
String[] charArray = new String[] {"a", "b", "c"};        
inPhoneData = conn.createArrayOf("CHAR", charArray);   
cstmt.setArray(1, inPhoneData);             // Set input parameter
cstmt.registerOutParameter (2, java.sql.Types.ARRAY);         
                                            // Register out parameters
cstmt.executeUpdate();                      // Call the stored procedure
Array outPhoneData = cstmt.getArray(2);                                   
                                            // Get the output parameter array
System.out.println("Parameter values from GET_EMP_DATA call: ");
String [] outPhoneNums = (String [])outPhoneData.getArray();
                                            // Retrieve output data from the
                                            // JDBC Array object into a Java
                                            // String array
for(int i=0; i<outPhoneNums.length; i++) {
  System.out.print(outPhoneNums[i]); 
  System.out.println();  
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and got `org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.UnableToCreateStatementException: Exception while binding 'output' [statement:"begin SELECT DISTINCT scu.LOGIN BULK COLLECT INTO :output from sc_users scu; end;", rewritten:"begin SELECT DISTINCT scu.LOGIN BULK COLLECT INTO ? from sc_users scu; end;", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{output:org.jdbi.v3.core.statement.Call$OutParamArgument@1f4863e0}, finder:[]}]`

Comment: My method is:

`@SqlCall("begin SELECT DISTINCT scu.LOGIN BULK COLLECT INTO :output from sc_users scu; end;")
    @OutParameter(name = "output", sqlType = Types.ARRAY)
    OutParameters selectIds();`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working with the [Jdbi `Handle`](http://jdbi.org/#_handle):

```java
var query = "begin " +
         "SELECT a.id " +
         "BULK COLLECT " +
         "INTO :output " +
         "from indexes a; "
         "end;"

try( var call = handle.createCall( query )
   .registerOutParameter( "output", java.sql.Types.ARRAY, new CallableStatementMapper() // see note below
   {
      @Override
      public Object map( int position, CallableStatement stmt ) throws SQLException
      {
         return stmt.getArray( position );
      }
   } )
    // .bind( "anotherParam", "value" )
) {
   var out = call.invoke();

   return out.getObject( "output", Array.class );
}
```

**Note**: Make sure that output parameters are registered at first on the `Call` interface that `createCall` returns! Otherwise you get the mentioned exceptions.

Comment: I can't understand where you found the getArray method. It's not present in the OutParameters class: https://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/OutParameters.html

Comment: @AM, you're right. My code was wrong. Have another look.